# How to add a plugins in phonegap application?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

How to add a plugins in **phonegap** application ?

I want to use **toast notification** in phonegap application, I have read about some plugin but doesn't work in application.

Answer (score 0):

The [version on github](https://github.com/munnadroid/phonegap-Toast-Plugin) is slightly out of date but someone has posted an [updated version](http://teusink.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/phonegap-android-toast-plugin.html).

More than that, you need to be more specific about what's not working. I suggest to try and get the example on the updated version page working in a test project, then integrate the plugin into your application.